# How to update parent page after AJAX Model Popup Extender closes without postback?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, modalpopupextender

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC, and so because of lack of server controls, I'm trying to figure this out:

I have a button on an ASP.NET page (let's call it **Parent Page**), which when I press, opens a modal popup which has a form in it which the user fills in. When the form is submitted, I'd like to display the data the user entered in the modal popup on the **Parent Page**, without doing a postback. How can this be achieved while using MVC ?

The Models I'm using are given below. The **Parent Page** is for creating a **Team**, and the modal popup with take details of a **Player**. The details are then to be shown on the **Parent Page** in a grid-like view.

```
public class Team
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public string name {get; set;}
    public string slogan {get; set;}
    public string homeCity {get; set;}
    public List<Player> players {get; set;}
}

public class Player
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public string fullName {get; set;}
    public int age {get; set;}
    public string height {get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you submit the Form through ajax, you return the view of the parent page (complete page, or parent view). With simple jquery statements, you can close the modal popup, and then replace the page with the updated view. That's the easiest way.

You can extend this with partial view, so you don't lose the state of the parts of your page.

Comment: Actually I am returning PartialView() inside of View(), but I don't know which jQuery statements can be used to get the data from the modal popup ? I know how to close the dialog, etc.